# Azure Stream Analytics failed to trigger Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-stream-analytics

I have created a Azure Function to return the result to device when the device send data to Azure IoT hub. I follow the [tutorial](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns.md#query-example-send-data-to-multiple-outputs) to send the output to SQL and Azure function. Here is my ASA query.

```
WITH subquery as (
    SELECT 
    messageId,
    deviceId,
    temperature, 
    humidity,
    EventProcessedUtcTime,
    DemoML(temperature, humidity) as result1
    from DemoInput
    )

SELECT
    messageId as messageId,
    deviceId as deviceId,
    temperature as temperature,
    humidity as humidity,
    EventProcessedUtcTime as EventProcessedUtcTime,
    result1.[Scored Labels] as result,
    result1.[Scored Probabilities] as resultProbability
INTO
    [DemoOutput]
FROM
    [subquery]


SELECT
    *
INTO
    [c2d]
FROM
    [subquery]
```

I do not know why it would not trigger the Azure function. But when I change the last line from [subquery] to [DemoInput] then it will work. Why is this happen?

Comment: What about the DemoOutput? Is it working? For test purpose, add the output for Blob storage and replace in your query c2d to DemoOutputBlob.

Comment: The DemoOutput is output to SQL. It is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query for test purpose, only. Note, that I took out your DemoML function and the output is for Blob storage. You should see outputs in the AF and Blob storage:

```
WITH subquery as (
     SELECT 
       System.Timestamp as time,
       temperature, 
       humidity,
       EventProcessedUtcTime,
       IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId as deviceId,
       IoTHub.MessageId as messageId
     FROM
       DemoInput Timestamp by time
    )

SELECT
    messageId as messageId,
    deviceId as deviceId,
    temperature as temperature,
    humidity as humidity,
    EventProcessedUtcTime as EventProcessedUtcTime
INTO
    DemoOutputBlob
FROM
    subquery


SELECT
    *
INTO
    c2d
FROM
    subquery
```

Comment: Hi, I asked the question in another post as I realised the problem is the Azure function app. Can you help me to take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604272/c-sharp-jsonconvert-deserializeanonymoustype-failed